# Split ArrayList of Strings into another ArrayList of Strings with the return type being a List, and not void

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, return

My code is supposed to return an Arraylist of words when given another Arraylist of strings.

For example:

**Input:**

```
["Hello there"]
```

**Output:**

```
["Hello","there"]
```

So far I have:

```
public static List<String> stringToListOfWords(List<String> list )
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++)
            {
                String[] temp = (list.get(i).split("\\s+"));
                ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp));

            }
            return(wordList);

        }
```

I've tried moving the wordList in the for loop but then I get the error saying that the return type is wrong. I got it to work for when the return type is `void` but I need it to return as a `list`.

Any help would be great!

Comment: If `ArrayList<String> wordList` is declared within some curly braces and is not returned from within the curly braces then it will go out of scope

Comment: Try reading polymorphism of OOP in java :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should create a single `ArrayList` before the loop and add to it all the words inside the loop:

```
public static List<String> stringToListOfWords(List<String> list )
{   
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<> ();
    for(int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {
        String[] temp = list.get(i).split("\\s+");
        wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
    }
    return wordList;

}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the advice I thought my mistake was much more complicated than it needed to be!

Comment: Is there any reason for not writing `i <= list.size() - 1` as `i < list.size()`?

Comment: @STaefi both are equivalent. I went with the OP's choice, since there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that wasn't the question, so I don't see a need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can drop the loop and use a `forEach` instead

```
public static List<String> stringToListOfWords(List<String> list) {
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(item->{
        String[] temp = item.split("\\s+");
        wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
    });
    return wordList;
}
```

or if you want to use Streams here's a one liner

```
public static List<String> stringToListOfWords(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(word -> word.split("\\s+"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Does not really change much does it.

Comment: Nice job +1, but is it recommended to add to an existing list from within a stream?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't know if its recommended but I have edited my answer and now it should not add to an existed list.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using streams as of Java 8:

```
public static List<String> stringToListOfWords(List<String> list){
    return list.stream()
               .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")).stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me why you decided to use flatmap and then stream it instead of using a regular map and then a flat map like my answer?

Comment: @Rab As `s.split("\\s+")` returns a `String[]` I decided to make a Stream of it and then make it flat to change it from Stream of Stream to a single stream. But now I saw your answer. It seems more elegant to me! Somehow more understandable!